# JavaScriptでGzip圧縮できるライブラリ「Zlib.js」の使い方を教えてください。

Tags: javascript

https://pisuke-code.com/javascript-usage-of-zlib-js/

上記がその詳細の記事なのですが、専門的過ぎて初心者の私にはよく理解できなかったので、易しく教えてくださるプロフェッショナルの方よろしくお願い致します。

Yahoo!ショッピングストアを利用しており、トリプル機能を使ってhtmlでショップを一から作っています。そのショップページ表示速度を上げるために.htaccessを使ってGzip圧縮とキャッシュ設定しようとしたところ、.htaccessが使えないことが分かりました。

それで調べたところ、JavaScriptでGzip圧縮できる方法があるのを知りました。

ですが、重複しますが知識がなくお手上げ状態です。

html/css/js の３つをJavaScriptを利用してGzip圧縮させたいです。

どのようなソースコードを記載すればよろしかったでしょうか？

何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 「ページ速度を上げる」とはサーバ→閲覧者方向の転送速度っすか？それとも閲覧者→サーバ方向っすか？　前者ならこの話は全く無意味っす。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
私の認識では、閲覧者→サーバ方向と考えております。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 閲覧者→サーバ方向ということはファイルのアップロードの速度を上げたいということですか？

Comment: すみません、初心者なもので説明がうまくないのですが、ショップ表示の速度をあげたいのです。ですが、ヤフーショップは.htaccessの使用を禁止しているので、gzipで圧縮させることができません。その代わりを上記ライブラリを見つけたのですが、使用方法が分からずに質問させて頂きました。

Comment: ショップの表示速度を上げるにはサーバ→閲覧者方向の転送速度を上げる必要があります。参考にしているのは、閲覧者→サーバ方向のデータを圧縮しているので方向が逆です。

Comment: ヤフーショッピングのようなサービスの場合、デフォルトでmod_deflateなどが有効になっていませんか？ご自分のサイトを例えばChromeで開いてDevToolsのNetworkタブでResponse Headersを見るとcontent-encoding: gzipが含まれてませんか？

Answer (score 5):

ショップのページを閲覧者が見るとき遅いのであれば、改善するべきはサーバ→閲覧者方向のデータ転送に要する時間です。もし「データ転送速度が遅い（回線が細い）」のであればサーバ側で `gzip` 圧縮を行うことでデータ転送量を減らす（代わりにサーバ CPU 負荷は上昇します) ことができます。これをする手段として

- `httpd.conf` で `mod_deflate` を有効にする
- `php.ini` で `zlib.output_compression = on` を有効にする ([php](/questions/tagged/php) を使っているとき)
- 事前に静的コンテンツを `gzip` 圧縮しておき `.htaccesss` で自動 `rewrite` を有効にする

などがあります。 https://syncer.jp/how-to-make-gzip

いずれにせよ設定ファイル `httpd.conf` や `.htaccess` を操作する権限が必要です。全くないなら手が付けられません。あと著名どころのサイトなら上記のような設定は既にされている可能性がありますので確認してみると良さそう。

遅い原因は回線太さとは限らないので、あてずっぽうで対策しても無駄です。どこが遅いのか調査してから手を付けるべきでしょう。

---

紹介記事は逆方向、閲覧者→サーバ方向のデータ転送時間の短縮のために閲覧者側でアップロード前にデータを圧縮するためのものです。なので紹介記事を参考にしてもサーバ→閲覧者方向の転送時間は短くなりません。あなたの目的にはそぐわないということになります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。大変よく分かりました。詳しく記載していただき、感謝いたします。

Answer (score 3):

手段が目的になってしまっています。「ページ速度を上げる」のであれば、遅い箇所を特定し、その部分を改善する必要があります。
Zlib.jsを使用してもページ速度は上がりません。

---

> Googleのスピードなんとかと言う、表示速度を計測するサイトを利用したところ、html/css/javascriptをgzipで圧縮するようにとありました。（略） これでは速度は上がらないのですか？

上がりません。[パレートの法則](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%91%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E6%B3%95%E5%89%87)を理解すべきです。仮にZlib.jsを使用することで当該箇所の所要時間が極限まで短縮でき `0` となったとして、ページ速度全体に占める割合がわずかであれば、ページ速度そのものは上がりません。
例えば、データの準備に20秒、通信に1秒、描画に3秒（数値はでたらめです）要していた場合、Zlib.jsで通信が効率化されたとしても全体としては24秒→23秒でしかない、という話です。

ですから最初に指摘したように、遅い箇所を特定する必要があります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。Googleのスピードなんとかと言う、表示速度を計測するサイトを利用したところ、html/css/javascriptをgzipで圧縮するようにとありました。ですが、ヤフーショップでは.htaccessが使えないので代わりにjavaScriptで圧縮できるライブラリを探していましたが、これでは速度は上がらないのですか？